# Почему в список переносится только 2 элемента?

Tags: python

```
messages = [1, 2, 3, 4]
sent_messages = []

for i in messages:
    message = messages.pop(0)
    sent_messages.append(message)

print(sent_messages)
```

Почему в список sent_messages переносится только **2** **элемента** `1, 2`, когда в самом списке откуда происходит перенос всего **4** **элемента**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нельзя удалять элементы итерируемого объекта. Сначала создайте новый, потом удалите старый объект.